# Application Icon For ClickOnce deployment

Tags: deployment, icons, clickonce, installation

When you go to install a application that has been onceclick deployed and you have downloaded the setup file when you click on it it starts checking for a new version and what not. While it does this it has a pretty rubbish icon https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yU2q.png is there any way to change this.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the icon that is associated with your application, in the Start Menu, after it has been installed?  If so, you can change that within your Projects options dialog.  Let me know if this is what you want to change and I'll post a step-by-step walkthrough of the process.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Chester Hong](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/113635b7-b7fa-4ce5-82c8-30f14e6d568f) you're stuck with this.  Dennis van der Stelt writes that you can disable the automatic update check and [code your own](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce.aspx).  This would give you control over what appears on screen at the time.